# How to access the initial values of the redux state?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, local-storage

I have a problem and I hope you can help me. I did a implementation of redux and using local storage I managed to keep the data when reloading the page. I can see them from the redux extension.

Why the state after reloading the page is in a different format? initially is a JavaScript object, after reloading a Map object

The problem is that accessing those properties after the page has been reloaded is lost or rather, they come in a different way. For clarity, this is how you see the properties without reloading the page by making a `console.log` from the component:

[consolelog component before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/339WQ.png)

and this is how looks the `console.log` after reloading the page, the properties are contained in another property called `nodes`

[consolelog component after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhRny.png)

My state looks the same both without reloading or reloading the page:

[store redux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MuVa.png)

The implementation of load and save state is as follows:

```
import {fromJS} from 'immutable'

export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serializedData = localStorage.getItem('state')
    if (serializedData === null){
      return undefined 
    }
    return (JSON.parse(serializedData)) 
  } catch (error) {
    return undefined 
  }
}

export const saveState = (state) => {
  try {
    let serializedData = JSON.stringify(state.toJS())
    localStorage.setItem('state', serializedData)
  } catch (error) {

  }
}
```

and my configureStore looks like this:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router/immutable';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import createReducer from './reducers';
import sagas from '../utils/sagas';

import {loadState, saveState} from '../storage/index'
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();


export default function configureStore(initialState ={}, history) {

  const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history)];

  const enhancers = [applyMiddleware(...middlewares)];
  const initialData = loadState();

  const composeEnhancers = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
    && typeof window === 'object'
    && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
      ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
          shouldHotReload: false,
        })
      : compose;
  /* eslint-enable */
  const store = createStore(

    createReducer(),
    fromJS(initialData),
    composeEnhancers(...enhancers),


  );
  store.subscribe(function(){
    saveState(store.getState())
  })

  // Extensions
  sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);
  store.injectedReducers = {}; // Reducer registry
  store.injectedSagas = {}; // Saga registry

  return store ;
}
```

Reducers:

```
import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form/immutable';

import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
//import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router/immutable';
import history from 'utils/history';
import * as storage from 'redux-storage';

// Global Reducers
import languageProviderReducer from 'containers/LanguageProvider/reducer';
import authReducer from './modules/authReducer';
import uiReducer from './modules/uiReducer';
import initval from './modules/initFormReducer';
import adminReducer from './modules/adminReducer'

/**
 * Creates the main reducer with the dynamically injected ones
 */
export default function createReducer(injectedReducers = {}) {
  const rootReducer = storage.reducer(combineReducers({
    form,
    ui: uiReducer,
    initval,
    authReducer,
    adminReducer,

    router: connectRouter(history),
    ...injectedReducers,
  }));

  // Wrap the root reducer and return a new root reducer with router state
  const mergeWithRouterState = connectRouter(history);
  return mergeWithRouterState(rootReducer);
}
```

mapStateToProps in the component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  state: state.get('authReducer','authReducer')
});
```

I think it can be the format in which the loadState() is loaded but I don't understand why in the redux extension you see the state exactly the same as without reloading. Any suggestions or how could I correct this?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what the issue you're encountering is. Can you try to rephrase what the problem is?

Comment: edited: Why the state after reloading the page is a different format? initially is a JavaScript object, after reloading a Map object

Comment: Seems to be `fromJS`, right? https://egghead.io/lessons/immutable-js-using-fromjs-to-convert-plain-javascript-objects-into-immutable-data

Comment: I think it would help if we could see where the console.logs are added. as Nick mentioned already, it looks like `fromJS` converts your initialstate into a Map.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you initially load the state in `configureStore`, you use 
[fromJS](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS). By default, POJOs are converted to `Map` instances.

You need to decide how you want your data to be stored, if you want an immutable object that *feels* like a POJO then consider using a `Record`.

Comment: How i can use Record in my inicial state?

Comment: @danielm2402 setup a record definition and then create an instance of said record when setting the stage e.g. `new MyStateRecord(initialState)`

Comment: I try with Record, but it gives me problems

Comment: @danielm2402 well what sort of problems? A `Record` supports all the same methods as `Map` therefore they should be interchangeable